# Can I still sideload .ipa files on M1 Macs?

Tags: macos, apple-silicon, gatekeeper, ios

I have been trying to install the Google Home iOS app on my 2021 Macbook Pro (M1X)

I found some .ipa files online, but I got these error messages.

[image]

[image]

How can I tell if an arbitrary ipa is code signed and ideally, if it will run before I try and get these errors?

Comment: I’ve tagged edited this to be one question to directly address code signing of ipa on macOS. Please ask a follow on question if you have a related question rather than tacking two different questions at the end. Apple support will help you if you can’t install official apps from the official store and we can help too if you post that new question with a link to the app in question that’s official.

Comment: I get the sense there are ways to use Xcode to sign an ipa so it'll run on arm64 Macs even if the developer (in this case, Google) hasn't given permission for that.  I think there are some tools that help with this aspect of sideloading, but I'm not naming/linking to 'em to stay away from any SE red lines I'm not aware of, and I don't know for sure.  Careful not to infect your computer.